# Вам нужно улучшить работу финансового приложения, чтобы оно стало удобным для пользователя

Tags: java

Как заставить его работать? Выдает ошибку.

Ошибка компиляции:
/sandbox/submission/Praktikum.java:30: error: int cannot be dereferenced
if (currency.equals("USD")) {
^

/sandbox/submission/Praktikum.java:32: error: int cannot be dereferenced
} else if (currency.equals("EUR")) {
^

/sandbox/submission/Praktikum.java:34: error: int cannot be dereferenced
} else if (currency.equals("JPY")) {
^

3 errors

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Praktikum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double rateUSD = 78;
        double rateEUR = 85;
        double rateJPY = 0.74;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Сколько денег у вас осталось до зарплаты?");
        double moneyBeforeSalary = scanner.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Сколько дней до зарплаты?");
        int daysBeforeSalary = scanner.nextInt();

        while (true){//настройте бесконечный цикл здесь
            System.out.println("Что вы хотите сделать? ");
            System.out.println("1 - Конвертировать валюту");
            System.out.println("2 - Получить совет");
            System.out.println("0 - Выход"); // Новый пункт меню, осталось только реализовать логику

            int command = scanner.nextInt();

            if (command == 1) {
                System.out.println("В какую валюту хотите конвертировать? Доступные варианты: 1 - USD, 2 - EUR или 3 - JPY.");
                int currency = scanner.nextInt() ;

                if (currency.equals("USD")) {
                    System.out.println("Ваши сбережения в долларах: " + moneyBeforeSalary / rateUSD);
                } else if (currency.equals("EUR")) {
                    System.out.println("Ваши сбережения в евро: " + moneyBeforeSalary / rateEUR);
                } else if (currency.equals("JPY")) {
                    System.out.println("Ваши сбережения в йенах: " + moneyBeforeSalary / rateJPY);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Валюта не поддерживается.");
                }

            } else if (command == 2) {
                if (moneyBeforeSalary < 3000) {
                    System.out.println("Сегодня лучше поесть дома. Экономьте и вы дотянете до зарплаты!");
                } else if (moneyBeforeSalary < 10000) {
                    if (daysBeforeSalary < 10) {
                        System.out.println("Окей, пора в Макдак!");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Сегодня лучше поесть дома. Экономьте и вы дотянете до зарплаты!");
                    }
                } else if (moneyBeforeSalary < 30000) {
                    if (daysBeforeSalary < 10) {
                        System.out.println("Неплохо! Прикупите долларов и зайдите поужинать в классное место. :)");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Окей, пора в Макдак!");
                    }
                } else {
                    if (daysBeforeSalary < 10) {
                        System.out.println("Отлично! Заказывайте крабов!");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Неплохо! Прикупите долларов и зайдите поужинать в классное место. :)");
                    }
                }
            } else if (command == 0) {
                System.out.println("Выход");
            break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Извините, такой команды пока нет.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: это нам тест на сообразительность? типа, угадайте, что за ошибка и где?

Comment: Ну в заголовке же написано "**Вам** нужно улучшить...", так что работайте @Сергей.

Answer (score 0):

`int currency = scanner.nextInt();`  `currency` - целого типа, а далее по коду вы `currency.equals("USD")` как для `String` вы уж определитесь, что пользователь должен вводить при вопросе выбора валюты, цифры или код валюты.

Answer (score -1):

```
int command = scanner.nextInt();

if (command == 1) {
    System.out.println("В какую валюту хотите конвертировать? Доступные варианты: 1 - USD, 2 - EUR или 3 - JPY.");
    int currency = scanner.nextInt() ;

    if (currency == 1) {
        System.out.println("Ваши сбережения в долларах: " + moneyBeforeSalary / rateUSD);
    } else if (currency == 2) {
        System.out.println("Ваши сбережения в евро: " + moneyBeforeSalary / rateEUR);
    } else if (currency == 3) {
        System.out.println("Ваши сбережения в йенах: " + moneyBeforeSalary / rateJPY);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Валюта не поддерживается.");
    }
```